# Ordering a complex unordered list with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I am looking for a way to sort a fairly complicated html unordered list using either standard javascript or jQuery.

Please view the HTML, the order needs to be alphabetical and based on the HTML found inside the `".keywordType span value"` but needs to construct the order of the top level li (with the unique keyword_xxx). I've just pasted 2 of the list items out of dozens.

```
<ul class="keywords">
    <li id="keyword_185">
        <div class="icon_keyword"></div>
        <input type="hidden" class="keywordLabel" value="More opening hours">
        <div class="data-wrapper">
            <div class="keywordType">
                <span class="oh">Payment methods</span>
            </div>
            <div class="keywordValue">
                <span id="keyword_185" class="oh">Credit Card, PayPal</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="edit" title="Edit keywords"></a>
        <a class="delete" title="Delete keywords"></a>
    </li>
    <li id="keyword_192">
        <div class="icon_keyword"></div>
        <input type="hidden" class="keywordLabel" value="Monday to Friday: 8:30am to 6:30pm Saturday: 9pm to 6:30pm Sunday: 10 - 4pm">
        <div class="data-wrapper">
            <div class="keywordType">
                <span class="oh">Opening Hours</span>
            </div>
            <div class="keywordValue">
                <span id="keyword_192" class="oh">Monday to Friday: 8:30am to 6:30pm<br>Saturday: 9pm to 6:30pm<br>Sunday: 10 - 4pm</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="edit" title="Edit keywords"></a>
        <a class="delete" title="Delete keywords"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Comment: This may be better suited for a serverside sort or a jquery table/grid.

Comment: Maybe the jSort jquery plugin can do the trick?

Comment: Can you please post your expected result?

Comment: Wes - I've little control over the HTML unfortunately! As it's doing a heck of a little before me taking over.
Sorry if it wasn't clear James Hill, the expected result was to reorder the <li> elements using the selector ".keywordType span" html value
TonioElGringo, thanks that's exactly what I was looking for. I'll also study the code to understand JS sorting better.

Comment: You're root problem here looks like overly complex html.  I'd look into a better structure for that so that problems like this don't keep popping up.

Comment: Tchalvak yes I agree, but I'm taking over a website that has server side and existing client side functionality that's closely tied to this html structure, unfortunately.

Comment: [jQuery.fn.sortElements](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/) is the only fair way for years in my opinion. I used it throu greasemonkey scripts at first, so no need to change anything to the html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var list = $('ul.keywords');
var listItems = $('li', list);

listItems.sort(function (a, b) {
    return $(a).text() > $(b).text() ? 1 : -1;
});

list.append(listItems);
```

You can [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the list of elements (jQuery objects have all the methods of `Array`, including [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)).

In the comparison function simply compare the text content of the list items. Individual letters will be subsequently compared according to their position in the alphabet (Unicode table, actually). For example, `k > a` is `true`.

Finally, just re-append the items to the list.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/igesic

Comment: Thanks, very simple solution I don't need it to do anything beyond this :-)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this, it exactly matches your requirement.

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
var arr;
$('.keyword span').each( function( i, el){
    arr[i] = $(el).text();
});
arr.sort();
```

I tested it on this question page, the code below orders the list of related questions in the right hand col.

```
var arr;
$('.question-hyperlink').each( function( i, el){
    arr[i] = $(el).text();
});
arr.sort();
```